# Adding Image Count to Multigallery

Tags: php, shortcode, gallery

Ok so I am using the [multigallery] function and it works fine, but one thing I want to add.

Here is the code that I am using for the multigallery in my functions.php file

```
function get_random_gallery_images(){ 
global $wpdb,$post; 
$ids = ""; 
$counter = 0; 
$number_of_posts = 6; 
$args = array( 
'post_type' => 'attachment', 
'numberposts' => 6, 
'post_status' => null, 
'orderby' => 'rand', 
'post_parent' => $post->ID 
); 
$attachments = get_posts($args); 
if ($attachments) { 
foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
if ($counter != 0) { 
$ids .= ','.$attachment->ID; 
} 
else { 
$ids .= $attachment->ID; 
} 
$counter++; 
} 
} 
return $ids; }
function multi_gallery_shortcode()
{
$attachment_ids = get_random_gallery_images();
return do_shortcode('[gallery columns="6" order="ASC" orderby="menu_order"      include="'.$attachment_ids.'" link="gallery"]');
}
add_shortcode('multigallery', 'multi_gallery_shortcode');
```

And here is how it looks

[image]

It's working Great but here are some functions that I want to add

[image]

I want to add the photo count to the shortcode with css ass well, and the title above the thumbnails, but the problem is, I don't know where to add the codes or the `<div>` codes either, can anyone help me with this problem.

Here is a code i have to call the number of photos, but where do i add this for it to show up in the [multigallery] shortcode.

```
<?php
$attachments = get_children(array('post_parent'=>$post->ID));
$nbImg = count($attachments);
echo '<span class="galNum">'.$nbImg.'</span> Photos.';
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
function multi_gallery_shortcode($atts, $content=null) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
                'pid' => 0,
        ), $atts ) );

    //format input
    $pid = intval($pid);

    // construct a post object dependent on the input value
    if($pid>0){
        // query a post object
        $pobj = get_post( $pid );
    }else{
        global $post;
        // current post object
        $pobj = &$post;
    }

    // construct gallery title
    $gallery_title = $pobj->post_title; // customize to your needs

    // construct gallery url
    $gallery_url = ""; // default first image gallery url
    $attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_first_gallery_image($pobj->ID),'thumbnail'); // customize  to your needs
    if(isset($attributes[0]))
        $gallery_url = $attributes[0];

    // format output:
    $before     = sprintf('<div class="gallery-before"><a href="%s">%s</a></div>', $gallery_url , $gallery_title );
    $gallery_sc = sprintf('[gallery columns="1" order="ASC" orderby="menu_order" include="%s" link="gallery"]',get_random_gallery_images($pobj->ID));
    $after      = sprintf('<span class="galNum">%d</span> Photos.', get_total_attachments($pobj->ID));

    return $before.do_shortcode($gallery_sc).$after;
}
add_shortcode('multigallery', 'multi_gallery_shortcode');
```

where the three helper functions are:

```
function get_random_gallery_images($post_id){ 
    global $wpdb; 
    $ids = ""; 
    $args = array( 
        'post_type'      => 'attachment', 
        'post_mime_type' => 'image', 
        'posts_per_page' => 6, 
        'post_status'    => 'any', 
        'orderby'        => 'rand', 
        'post_parent'    => $post_id, 
    ); 
    $attachments = get_posts($args); 
    if ($attachments) { 
        $tmp=array();
        foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
                $tmp[] = $attachment->ID; 
        }  
        $ids=implode(",",$tmp);
    } 
    return $ids; 
}
```

and

```
function get_total_attachments($post_id){
    $args=array(
        'post_parent'     => $post_id, 
        'post_mime_type'  => 'image', 
        'post_type'       => 'attachment',
    ); 
    return count(get_children( $args ));
}
```

and finally

```
function get_first_gallery_image($post_id){ 
    global $wpdb; 
    $id = 0; 
    $args = array( 
        'post_type' => 'attachment', 
        'post_mime_type' => 'image', 
        'posts_per_page' => 1, 
        'post_status' => 'any', 
        'orderby' => 'date', 
        'order' => 'DESC', 
        'post_parent' => $post_id, 
    ); 
    $attachments = get_posts($args); 
    if (isset($attachments[0])) { 
        $id = $attachments[0]->ID; 
    } 
    return $id; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you this is perfect, Also how do i add to the title this code `'. get_attachment_link($attachment->ID) . '` @birgire

Comment: and to the photo count

Comment: I added two variables that you can play with: `$gallery_title` and `$gallery_url`, so you can add your custom title and url. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, i added this to the url `'. get_attachment_link($attachment->ID) . '` but it didn't work, it's suppose to grabe the attachment page url of the first image uploaded to the post, how can i fix it to work

Comment: ok, I updated the code. It is a kind of a skeleton but I'm sure you can work it out further ;-)