# Showing a different gallery in a seperate post

Tags: php, shortcode, gallery

i am using the `[multigallery]` function and I was wondering if there is a way to use the function to call attachments from another post.

For example if i was writing a post about taylor swift and I wanted to include attachments from another taylor swift post using the multigallery shortcode how would I do so.

Like by adding `id=` to the shortcode `[multigallery id=???]` where the id would be the post number and it will grab attachments from that post.

here is the code that i am currently using in my function.php file

```
function multi_gallery_shortcode(){
global $post;
$before     = sprintf('<div class="gallery-before">%s</div>',$post->post_title); 
$gallery_sc = sprintf('<div id="gallery-1">[gallery columns="6" order="ASC" orderby="menu_order" include="%s" link="gallery"]</div>',get_random_gallery_images($post->ID));
$after      = sprintf('<div class="gallery-after"><span class="galNum">%d</span> Photos</div><div style="clear:both;"></div>', get_total_attachments($post->ID));
return $before . do_shortcode($gallery_sc) . $after;
}

function get_random_gallery_images($post_id){ 
global $wpdb; 
$ids = ""; 
$args = array( 
    'post_type'      => 'attachment', 
    'post_mime_type' => 'image', 
    'posts_per_page' => 6, 
    'post_status'    => 'any', 
    'orderby'        => 'rand', 
    'post_parent'    => $post_id, 
); 
$attachments = get_posts($args); 
if ($attachments) { 
    $tmp=array();
    foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
            $tmp[] = $attachment->ID; 
    }  
    $ids=implode(",",$tmp);
} 
return $ids; 
}

function get_total_attachments($post_id){
$args=array(
    'post_parent'     => $post_id, 
    'post_mime_type'  => 'image', 
    'post_type'       => 'attachment',
); 
return count(get_children( $args ));
}

add_shortcode('multigallery', 'multi_gallery_shortcode');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this function instead of your `multi_gallery_shortcode()`:

```
function multi_gallery_shortcode($atts, $content=null) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
                'pid' => 0,
        ), $atts ) );

    //format the input
    $pid = intval($pid);

    // construct a post object dependent on the input value
    if($pid>0){
        // query a post object
        $pobj = get_post( $pid );
    }else{
        global $post;
        // current post object
        $pobj = &$post;
    }

    // construct gallery title
    $gallery_title = $pobj->post_title; // customize to your needs

    // construct gallery url
    $gallery_url = ""; // default first image gallery url
    $attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_first_gallery_image($pobj->ID),'thumbnail'); // customize  to your needs
    if(isset($attributes[0]))
        $gallery_url = $attributes[0];

    // format output:
    $before     = sprintf('<div class="gallery-before"><a href="%s">%s</a></div>', $gallery_url , $gallery_title );
    $gallery_sc = sprintf('[gallery columns="1" order="ASC" orderby="menu_order" include="%s" link="gallery"]',get_random_gallery_images($pobj->ID));
    $after      = sprintf('<span class="galNum">%d</span> Photos.', get_total_attachments($pobj->ID));

    return $before.do_shortcode($gallery_sc).$after;
}
```

where you use it like this in your posts/pages:

```
[multigallery pid="1234"]
```

where `pid` is the post id.

Comment: Thank you that works, only one thing though, how do i get it to grab the title of the post in which id i used @birgire

Comment: great, it should get the title via `$p->post_title`, where `$p` is either the current post object or the post object with post id `$pid`.

Comment: but it's grabbing from the current post instead of the post id thats attached to the multigallery code @birgire

Comment: I updated the code

Comment: Thank you, but i removed the `construct gallery url` because it broke the site, but everything else is working fine, THANK YOU :) @birgire

Comment: aha ;-) Please check out the extra helper function `get_first_gallery_image()` that I used here : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/94846/adding-image-count-to-multigallery/94885#94885